# Setup wp_schedule_event within a custom plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, wp-cron

I am using `WordPress 4.9.6` and I am trying to create a plugin that pulls data from an external API.

See below my current code:

**myPlugin.php**

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: myPlugin
description: Get Data via APIs
Version: 1.0
Author: Batman
License: GPLv2 or later
Text Domain: myPlugin
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

class My_Plugin {

      /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        define( 'MyPlugin_FILE', __FILE__ );
        define( 'MyPlugin_DIR', trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
        define( 'MyPlugin_VERSION', '0.0.1' );
        register_activation_hook( basename( MyPlugin_DIR ) . '/' . basename( MyPlugin_FILE ), array( $this, 'activate' ) );
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'includes' ) );
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'maybe_update' ) );
    }

    public function activate() {
        $this->includes();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

    public function includes() {
        include_once( MyPlugin_DIR . 'includes/WhatToMineAPI.php' );
    }

    /**
     * Maybe update MyPlugin.
     */
    public function maybe_update() {
        $version = get_option( 'MyPlugin_version', 0 );
        if ( version_compare( $version, MyPlugin_VERSION, '<' ) ) {
            $this->create_tables();
            update_option( 'MyPlugin_version', MyPlugin_VERSION );
        }
    }
}
new My_Plugin();
```

**WhatToMineAPI.php**

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class WhatToMineAPI {

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'setupCronJob_whatToMine', 'setupCronJob');
        add_action( 'update_whatToMine_api', 'updateWhatToMineAPI');

        // variables
        $whatToMineURL = "http://whattomine.com/coins.json";
    }

    public function setupCronJob() {
        //Use wp_next_scheduled to check if the event is already scheduled
        $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'update_whatToMine_api' );

        //If $timestamp == false schedule daily backups since it hasn't been done previously
        if( $timestamp == false ){
            //Schedule the event for right now, then to repeat daily using the hook 'update_whatToMine_api'
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'twicedaily', 'update_whatToMine_api' );
        }
    }

    public function updateWhatToMineAPI() {

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $response = $client->request('GET', $whatToMineURL);

    }


}
new WhatToMineAPI();
```

I have installed the plugin [WP-Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) to  get an overview of my running cron-jobs. However, my cron-job `update_whatToMine_api` cannot be found within the table?

[image]

Is my current cron-setup wrongly done?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Where are you calling `setupCronJob()`?

Comment: @kero Basically, when I activate my plugin the cron-job should also get activated. I thought that `add_action` does this job for me. Any suggestions how to call setupCronJob, when activating the plugin? I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: if you haven't read it already, please check the [official documentation on WP-Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/).

The problem in your code is this line

```
    add_action( 'setupCronJob_whatToMine', 'setupCronJob');
```

You're defining a new action `setupCronJob_whatToMine` and add the `setupCronJob` method to it. But as this is a custom action you just created, it will never be called (eg via `do_action('setupCronJob_whatToMine');`).

So instead of adding it to an action, you can call `setupCronJob()` directly to set up the event scheduling.

You can do it in the `init` action. However, this will add the logic to every page load, which is unnecessary. A cron like needs to be set up only once.

So I'd add the Cron in the [activation hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/activation-deactivation-hooks/) (and don't forget to remove it in the deactivation hook).

***Simple code example:***

**MyPlugin.php**

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array(My_Plugin::class, 'activate') );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array(My_Plugin::class, 'deactivate') );

class MyPlugin
{

    public static function activate()
    {
        WhatToMineAPI::setupCronJob();
    }

    public static function deactivate()
    {
        WhatToMineAPI::unsetCronJob();
    }

    // your other methods

}
```

**WhatToMineAPI.php**

```
class WhatToMineAPI
{

    const CRON_HOOK = 'update_whatToMine_api';

    public static function setupCronJob()
    {
        //Use wp_next_scheduled to check if the event is already scheduled
        $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( self::CRON_HOOK );

        //If $timestamp === false schedule daily backups since it hasn't been done previously
        if( $timestamp === false ){
            //Schedule the event for right now, then to repeat daily using the hook 'update_whatToMine_api'
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'twicedaily', self::CRON_HOOK );
        }
    }

    public static function unsetCronJob()
    {
        // Get the timestamp for the next event.
        $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( self::CRON_HOOK );
        wp_unschedule_event( $timestamp, self::CRON_HOOK );
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action(self::CRON_HOOK, array($this, 'updateWhatToMineAPI'));
    }

    public function updateWhatToMineAPI()
    {
        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('GET', $whatToMineURL);
    }

}
```

---

Side note: When working with classes, you need to beware. Either use `add_action('...', array($this, 'methodName'))` but then you need `$this` or similar defined.

Alternatively you can use `static` methods like so `add_action('...', array(MySuperClass::class, 'staticMethodName'))`